# Prestashop 1.7.3.4 - Friendly URL doesn't work despite rewrite active

Tags: mod-rewrite, prestashop, friendly-url

I'm running PS 1.7.3.4 on ubuntu 16.04.4 x64 with LAMP (php 7.1)

I've enabled friendly URL right after the installation of my shop. From index.php it then changed to /en/ yielding in

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /en/ was not found on this server.

rewrite is enabled and active. The .htaccess reads

```
<IFMODULE mod_rewrite.c>
<IFMODULE mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IFMODULE>

RewriteEngine on
```

and was recreated by disabling / enabling friendly urls.

```
> a2emod rewrite
```

yields in Module rewrite already enabled. The URL is the servers IP address. No SSL used.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the Allowoverride All directive to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Disable friendly URL
- Enable force compile
- Delete all cache with the option Clear Smarty cache & Autoload cache in performance
- Disable force compile
- Enable friendly URL

Answer (score 0):

I just elaborating  Apury's solution,try this it will work for you.

**Step1:** sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

**Step2:** Update AllowOverride None  to AllowOverride All  , press ctrl+o then ctrl+x

[cleck here to see that update/change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqXAk.png)

**Step3:** sudo systemctl restart apache2

Now check you website now.

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel Advanced Parameters >Performance uncheck  "Apache optimization"
Then save changes.
Then check "Apache optimization" again and save changes.

This will recreate rewrite rules by prestashop in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove class_index.php in \app\cache\dev (with dev mode) or \app\cache\prod folder